# node-exporter node_filesystem_size_bytes-Indikatoren sind inkonsistent

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I encountered a problem about Prometheus monitoring indicators:
The node_filesystem_size_bytes indicator in node-exporter is inconsistent with the results of df query

[image]

[image]

df query results /home and / are inconsistent,but node-exporter query results are the same.
help help me.
My node-exporter is deployed in docker, configuration file:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  node-exporter:
    image: prom/node-exporter
    volumes:
      - /proc:/host/proc:ro
      - /sys:/host/sys:ro
      - /:/rootfs:ro
    command:
      - '--path.procfs=/host/proc'
      - '--path.sysfs=/host/sys'
      - '--collector.filesystem.ignored-mount-points'
      - "^/(sys|proc|dev|host|etc|rootfs/var/lib/docker/containers|rootfs/var/lib/docker/overlay2|rootfs/run/docker/netns|rootfs/var/lib/docker/aufs)($$|/)"
    ports:
      - 9100:9100
    restart: always

  cadvisor:
    image: google/cadvisor
    volumes:
      - /:/rootfs:ro
      - /var/run:/var/run:rw
      - /sys:/sys:ro
      - /var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro
    ports:
      - 18080:8080
    restart: always
```

Answer (score 0):

After I added the following parameters to the yaml config, the problem was solved:

```
  - '--path.rootfs=/rootfs'
```

[image]